# not available for deploy for this org error using VSCode

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, api, sandbox

I recently refreshed my sandbox and trying to deploy some new files, `myApexClass.cls`, to the sandbox through `VSCode`, but I am getting the following error message.

**Question**

How do I resolve this issue such that I can deploy my newly created Apex Class to the sandbox?

**What I tried that still doesn't work**

1. changing the Apex class version to one of the following: `49.0`, `50.0`, `51.0`
2. changing my package.xml file from the `manifest` folder to only include the Apex Class
3. changed the `<version>49.0</version>` to match the version in the API version in the Apex Class's meta file (e.g. `<apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>`

**Error message**

```
Not available for deploy for this organization
```

**Example package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
     <members>myApexClass</members>
     <name>ApexClass</name>
  </types>
  <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: If I am reading correctly, your original change was only to refresh your sandbox - you did nothing at that moment to your SF CLI or VS Code.  Did you re-authenticate your sandbox in VS Code after refreshing it?

Comment: @Moonpie i did re-authenticate and i even ran `sfdx auth:logout --all`

Comment: This seem to be issue with profile.  Do you have 'Author Apex' enabled on profile?

Comment: @Vinay I have enabled `Author Apex`, re-authenticated in VSCode, and tried pushing with no luck.